# On proving that a linear function is an isomorphism when the Kernel of the function is the set with the single element zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I am looking at a proof of the fact that a linear function is an isomorphism when the Kernel of the function is the set with single element zero.

Let $V,W$ be two finitely generated $K$-vector spaces with $\dim V = \dim W = n $ and let $f:V \rightarrow W$ be linear then if $Ker(f) = <0>$ we have that $f$ is an isomorphism.

The proof states that $\dim V = 0 + \dim Im(f)= n \implies Im(f) = W$.

this means that the function is surjective, and this is fine. The injectivity is stated as obvious.

This seems intuitively right (that a linear function that goes to a vector space of the same dimension as the input space is injective), but I am doubtful given that we can have infinite elements in both the domain and co-domain, could I be convinced by a couple of lines of proof?

Answer (score 2):

Let $v_1,v_2\in V$.  Since $\ker(f)=\{0\}$ we have
$$f(v_1)=f(v_2)\Rightarrow f(v_1-v_2)=0\Rightarrow v_1-v_2\in\ker(f)\Rightarrow v_1-v_2=0\Rightarrow v_1=v_2\ .$$
That is, overall we have proved
$$f(v_1)=f(v_2)\Rightarrow  v_1=v_2$$
and so $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Injectivity is equivalent to kernel being zero: $Ker(f) = \langle0\rangle$, since by the isomorphism theorem we have $Imf\cong V/Kerf=V/\langle0\rangle=V$